# Getting an error while calculating income data

Tags: python, numpy

I have been working on a project where I have to predict income based on some data now i have encoded my income because it was a categorical variable using this code

```
Income_encod = LabelEncoder() 
Income = Income_encod.fit_transform(income_raw)
```

Now i have some calculation which involves

```
Income.count()
```

But i getting an error as

> "numpy.ndarray object has no attribute 'count'"

Comment: Have you tried `len(Income)`?

Comment: Yes thankyou it worked

Answer (score 1):

You cannot use the method `count()` which is a list method on a numpy array.
If you just want to get the length of the income array, try

```
Income.size
```

or

```
Income.shape
```

or

```
len(Income)
```